# How can I access a property within a "if" statement?

Tags: javascript

Here is my block of code,obviously quite simple. Learning by myself but getting there!I'm trying to figure out how to compare two objects that I created out of my constructor. But I don't get the function to work. I'm not sure how to trigger the property within objects. Am I missing a fundamental knowledge here?
Don't want to sound cheezy, but thank you everyone for sharing and helping others-humanity. There's so much info available, and that is because of you. The ultimate goal of knowledge, is to share it.

```
function rectangle (length,breadth,colour){

    this.length= length;
    this.breadth= breadth;
    this.colour= colour;
    this.area= function(){
        return this.length * this.breadth;
    }  /**The property (area) value is a function.**/
}
```

```
var Rectangle1 = new rectangle (5,3.5,"Green");

var Rectangle2 = new rectangle (7, 5.5, "Green");
```

```
function compareRectangles (Rectangle1, Rectangle2){

/**How can I target the property "area" within 'if' statement? or Did I get it all wrong?**/

   if (Rectangle1 > Rectangle2){

   return console.log(Rectangle1 + " is greater than Rectangle2 ");
     }

   else  if (Rectangle1 < Rectangle2) {

     return console.log(Rectangle2 + "is greater than Rectangle1");
   }
   else {
     return console.log("They're same size");
   }
}
```

```
 compareRectangles(Rectangle1, Rectangle2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following (added extra comments for your learning experience):

```js
// capitalized Rectangle here to indicate it's a class (convention)
function Rectangle (length,breadth,colour){

  this.length = length;
  this.breadth = breadth;
  this.colour = colour;

  // removed quotes around area here
  this.area = function () { 
    return this.length * this.breadth;
  }

// removed the ; after the } as it's not necessary after function declarations
}

// renamed Rectangle to rectangle1 to align with what you use in the function
// also lowercased the variables because they're instances of a class and not the class constructor itself
function compareRectangles (rectangle1, rectangle2){
  // check the .area method of the rectangle
  // you can access properties and methods through a dot
  // since area is a function, you need to execute with () to get the return value
  if (rectangle1.area() > rectangle2.area()){
    // changed console logs to not use the instance in the log.
    // Since the instance is an object it would try to parse it as a string, resulting in showing [Object object] or something like that
    // if you do want to log the rectangle, you should probably split that by adding an argument:
    // console.log("the greater rectangle is:", rectangle1);
    console.log("Rectangle1 is greater than Rectangle2");
    // I changed your return value, since console.log returns nothing
    // I figured it would be more relevant to return the 'winning' rectangle
    return rectangle1;
  }
  else if (rectangle1.area() < rectangle2.area()) {
    console.log("rectangle2 is greater than rectangle1");
    return rectangle2;
  }
  else {
    console.log("They're same size");
    // no winning rectangle makes it return null, so you can recognize it when calling the function
    return null;
  }
}

// Removed capitals for the variables as they are not class constructors but instances of the class.
// Also changed this to let instead of var,
// you may want to read up on const/let and try to forget about the existence of var
// Currently these could be const since they are never reassigned, but I can imagine it is easier for you currently to stick to let instead
let rectangle1 = new Rectangle (5,3.5,"Green");
let rectangle2 = new Rectangle (7, 5.5, "Green");

// you'll need to 'send over' the rectangles that you're expecting in your function
let returnedValue = compareRectangles(rectangle1, rectangle2);
console.log('Received return value:', returnedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing their area property, use

```
Rectangle1.area(); //Notice the (), because you wanted to call that function in the...
Rectangle2.area(); //...code
```

Simply using `Rectangle1 > Rectangle2` will compare them as *objects*. These themselves cannot normally be compared via `>` and `<`. You need to compare them with some of their property, which I know you are trying to do. But look at your code.

```
if (Rectangle1 > Rectangle2){
   return console.log(Rectangle1 + " is greater than Rectangle ");
}
```

You only put `Rectangle1` in the left-hand side of the operator. That is an object. To access its property, for example, length, you use `Rectangle1.length`
So do the same to access the function `area`, `Rectangle1.area`, thus call the function via `Rectangle1.area()`.

```
if (Rectangle1.area() > Rectangle2.area()){
   return console.log(Rectangle1 + " is greater than Rectangle2 ");
}
```

Essentially, just use the syntax:

*object*.*property*

Answer (score 0):

Since the property is a function, you have to call it `Rectangle1.area()`

Also, you have to call the `compareRectangles()` function and pass the two rectangles you made:

```
function rectangle (length,breadth,colour){
     this.length = length;
     this.breadth = breadth;
     this.colour = colour;
     this.area = function(){
         return this.length * this.breadth;
     }  
};
function compareRectangles(r1, r2){
    if (r1.area() > r2.area()){
        return console.log("Rectangle 1 is greater than Rectangle 2");
    } else  if (r1.area() < r2.area()) {
        return console.log("Rectangle 2 is greater than Rectangle 1");
    } else {
        return console.log("They're same size");
    }
};

var Rectangle1 = new rectangle (5,3.5,"Green");
var Rectangle2 = new rectangle (7, 5.5, "Green");
compareRectangles(Rectangle1, Rectangle2)
```

Output:

```
Rectangle 2 is greater than Rectangle 1
```

Comment: Um, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to call the `area()` method on the object to get the value

```
function compareRectangles (Rectangle1, Rectangle2){

   if (Rectangle1.area() > Rectangle2.area()){

   return console.log("Rectangle1 is greater than Rectangle2");
     }
   else  if (Rectangle1.area() < Rectangle2.area()) {
     return console.log("Rectangle2 is greater than Rectangle1");
   }
   else {
     return console.log("They're same size");
   }
}
```

call the function with required arguments

```
compareRectangles(Rectangle1, Rectangle2);
```

(Your question is improved. Please, go through your question to see miskates you made)